# Recreate or change parameters of twitter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have a page with a twitter button. Before that twitter button I have an input field and a form to easily add the relevant hashtags of that page.
The purpose is to take the text of the inputfield to twitter. So it's in the inputfield of the twitter dialog box.

So I have the following code to show the button, taken from the twitter documentation:

```
<a  href="https://twitter.com/share" 
    class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en"
data-size="large" 
    data-count="none"
data-text="BLA"
id="tweetbutton">Tweet</a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                js=d.createElement(s);
                js.id=id;
                js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";                               
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
            }
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>
```

(I entered "BLA" as text, just as a test)

So when the value of my inputfield changes I do the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function appendTag(tag) {    
   var newValue = $('#bericht').val() + tag;        
   $('#tweetbutton').attr('data-text', newValue);

   twttr.widgets.load();                
}
</script>
```

In the documentation I read that "twttr.widgets.load();" should recreate the button. But it doesn't do that. I also tried adding the line "(document,"script","twitter-wjs");" beneath my function, but it didn't change the behavior.

Any points in the right direction? Maybe there is a better way to change the text attribute of the button on the go?

UPDATE:
I found that on ted.com they do something simular with the addthis api. But I want to do it withoud the api. So if you need to visualize what I want to do, check for example http://www.ted.com/talks/dan_phillips_creative_houses_from_reclaimed_stuff.html. They have an inputfield that is somehow linked to the tweet button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead of API button a custom button with all required attributes, and put onclick event url:

```
window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=<url>&text=<text>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=620,height=280');
```

This will behave like popup for twitter message.

Comment: Thx! Just tested this method and it will do what I want.
For future reference, you need to do a text.replace('#', '%23'); or your hashtags won't work.